# From where does Rabbi Nachman know that King David's Lyre possessed 5 strings?

Tags: chasidut-hasidism, king-david, breslov

In [Likutei Moharan 1:8:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Likutei_Moharan.8.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) Rabbi Nachman says:

(*Source From [Sefaria.org](https://www.sefaria.org)*)

> כי כנור של דוד היה של חמש נימין, כנגד חמשה חמשי תורה
>
> *[King] David's Lyre had 5 strings, corresponding to the 5 books of the Torah*

Is there a source from which Rabbi Nachman is drawing from to say that King David's Lyre had 5 strings? Or is this his own original idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This comes from Tikunei Zohar Tikuna Asira'ah ([here](http://www.hebrew.grimoar.cz/zohar/tikune_zohar.htm) page 25b), in discussing numerical connections between the 5 knots on tzitzis and the 5 first words of Shema and the 5 strings on King David's lyre:

> וכד ישראל אמרין שמע ודאי מארי חיוון שמטין גדפייהו באן אתר בכנפי מצוה דאתמר בהון על ארבע כנפות כסותך אשר תכסה בה דאיהו כגוונא דמעיל האפוד דפעמונים ורמונים אינון לקבל חליין וקשרין שולי המעיל אינון לקבל כנפי מצוה ואינון חמש קשרין לקבל שמע ישראל י"י אלקינ"ו י"י דאינון לקבל חמש נימין דכנור דדוד דהוה מנגן מאליו

It is also found on pages 27b, 28a, and 51b in other discussions, at the above link.

Comment: 120% that was a bar illan/otzar hachochma search right?